# Unity 3d Gun Recoil Animation IK Problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics

im having trouble with the hand IK of a -recoil shoot animation- that is on an override layer in the animator. I have it set up so that when I aim(left trigger), it allows me to shoot with another button(right trigger). I have it so the weight (hand IK) increases to 1 (in the rig layer) when I aim and decreases to 0 when I let go of the aim button.

The problem is that if I shoot the gun (uses recoil gun animation) and let go of the aim button immediately afterwards, the animation will continue to play but the IK will go to 0 and the hands will look all messed up.

I've tried setting the IK hand weight to 1 when he fires the gun, so he'll still hold onto it, but it doesn't work since shoot is only true if aim is being held down.

So overall I fire the gun, he does a recoil animation, and when you let go of aim too early, the animation looks all messed up like he's waving to you from behind his back. Like it aborts the animation or something.

```
  private void HandleMovementInput()
  {
    horizontalMovementInput = movementInput.x;
    verticalMovementInput = movementInput.y;
    animatorManager.HandleAnimatorValues(horizontalMovementInput, verticalMovementInput, runInput); 

    if (verticalMovementInput != 0 || horizontalMovementInput !=0) //running
    {
       

        if (aimingInput)                                                  
        {
            
            if (animatorManager.isAimingGunn == false)
            {
                shootInput = false;                                                                 
                
            }
        }
    }

    if (animatorManager.isAimingGunn)
    {
       
        animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight = 1; // IK weight
        animatorManager.rightHandIK.weight = 1;


        horizontalMovementInput = 0f; // joystick
        verticalMovementInput = 0f;
    }

    else if(animatorManager.isAimingGunn == false)
    {
       
        if(verticalMovementInput != 0 || horizontalMovementInput !=0) //running
        {
            animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight = 0;
        }

        animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight = 0; // IK weight
        animatorManager.rightHandIK.weight = 0;
      
    }
 
}
     
     private void HandleShoot()
{
    if (aimingInput) // must aim otherwise shootInput(right trigger on controller) wont work
    {
        if (shootInput)
        {
            shootInput = false;
            playerManager.UseCurrentWeapon();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. I used this code to tell the character to keep aiming if still in the current animation.This allows for the animation to finish before you set the Hand IK to 0.

```
      if(animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1).IsName("Pistol_Shoot"))
        {
            aimingInput = true;
        }
```

Also Due to it getting overly complicated I changed the aim cancel button to the top left trigger on the controller ( while aim is on the bottom left trigger).